# Customizing dialog text in KDE4 (Would you like to send this to narnia?)

Tags: language, opensuse, kde-4, opensuse-11.2

I'd really like it to say:

> "Would you like to send this to
>   Narnia?"

When I delete stuff in openSUSE 11.2 with KDE4. Perferably something easy like:

```
sed /trash/narnia/
```

I know how to do this in Windows and I'll be damned if Linux can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could change the the translation file and recompile KDE yourself, but hardly worth doing